# Density function for a multivariate Bernoulli-like distribution

Tags: distributions

I'm looking for a distribution to model a vector of $k$ binary random variables, $X_1, \ldots, X_k$.  Suppose I have observed that $\sum_i X_i = n$.  In this case I do not want to treat them as independent Bernoulli random variables.  Instead, I would like something like the multinomial:

$P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_k=x_k) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_k; n, p_1, \ldots, p_k) = \frac{n!}{x_1! \cdots x_k!} \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{x_i}$

but instead of the $x_i$ being nonnegative integers, I want them restricted to be either 0 or 1.  I have been trying to see if the [multivariate hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is appropriate, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: By the way, will the binomial not work for you? You have k trials and n successes. right?

Comment: Slightly different: I have $k$ different coins, each with a different probability (ie. $p_i$), and I have $n$ successes. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate distribution is [Wallenius's noncentral hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_hypergeometric_distributions).  Using an urn analogy, the problem is equivalent to picking $n$ of $k$ balls without replacement, where each ball is a different color: the parameters $p$ are analogous to the weights of picking a particular color.

The problem: it's not very convenient to work with, though there is an [R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiasedUrn/BiasedUrn.pdf).

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I wonder though if it's not the Fisher that's more appropriate here -- since in the urn formulation of the problem, N is observed after the experiment, and you condition on the sum.  Quite likely, I'm one of the "confused" the wikipedia article refers to. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

In light of your comments, here is an updated answer:

**Approach 1: Difficult to implement/analyze**

Consider the simple case of $k$ = 3 and $n$ = 2. In other words you toss 3 coins (with probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$). Then, the required mass function for the above case is:

$p_1 p_2 (1-p_3) + p_1 (1-p_2) p_3  + (1-p_1) p_2 p_3$

The above reduces to the [binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) if the probabilities $p_i$ are all identical.

In the general case, you will have ${k \choose n}$ terms where each term is unique with a structure similar to the one above.

**Approach 2: Easier to analyze/implement**

Instead of the above, you could model each $X_i$ as a [bernoulli variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with probability $p_i$. You could then assume that $p_i$ follows a [dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).

You would then estimate the model parameters by constructing the posterior distribution for $p_i$ conditional on observing $n$ successes.

<strike>If you can normalize by n and and assuming that treating them as probabilities/proportions makes sense in your context you can use the [dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).</strike>

Comment: I am already modeling the probability of each cell as a Dirichlet, $p \sim Dirichlet(\alpha)$.  Normalizing by $n$ wouldn't quite work since a cell with large $p_i$ would have small likelihood whenever $n$ is fairly large, even when we indeed observed $x_i=1$ (unnormalized).  Does that make any sense?

Comment: I am afraid you lost me by the mention of a 'cell' when the question does not mention this word at all. Could you provide some more context so that I can understand better?

Comment: Sorry: By cell I mean each $x_i$.

Comment: In other words, I want to sample $n$ integers between 1 and $k$ without replacement using the probability vector $p$.

Comment: This getting confusing to me. Your $X_i$ is either 0 or 1 but now you want to sample $n$ integers between 1 and $k$?

Comment: Sorry: I'm saying that it's an equivalent formulation to sample the indices of $X$ without replacement.  Then $x_i=1$ for those integers that are sampled and $x_i=0$ for those integers that are not.

Comment: In that case, you have basically the following scenario: You flip a coin $k$ times and your constraint is that you need $n$ successes as that will ensure that $X_i$ sum to $n$. This is a binomial distribution. If this satisfies your requirements I will change my answer. If it does not can you explain why this will not work?

Comment: Slightly different: I have $k$ different coins, each with a different probability (ie. $p_i$), and I have $n$ successes.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: For the second proposal, what is the form of this posterior?  Another Dirichlet?  It makes sense that the Dirichlet would be conjugate here, just like if we were using a multinomial.  But we're not using a multinomial.  So what is the pdf of the distribution you propose?  (It's a multivariate bernoulli that has been conditioned on observing n successes, right?)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a dirichlet. The bernoulli can be written as: $f(X_i;p_i) = p_i^{X_i} (1-p_i)^{1-X_i}$ which is not conjugate to the dirichlet. You will have to use Metropolis-Hastings to estimate the parameters.